# Invalid tag name "file-saver@2.0.1" when trying npm install

Tags: angular, npm, continuous-integration

I am facing an issue when building my Angular app in Azure Continous Integration.

Just before build step there is an npm install step in which its failing and triggering the below error

```
error Invalid tag name "file-saver@2.0.1": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes
```

Here is my Package.json file where filesaver is specified

```
"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
"dom-to-image": "^2.6.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
"html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
"html2pdf.js": "0.9.2",
"jquery": "^3.5.1",
"jspdf": "^1.5.2",
```

No idea why its only firing in Azure. Its (npm install) working fine locally.

Answer (score 0):

I believe file-saver@2.0.1 is a dependency of jspdf@1.5.2. Thats why you are getting the error for file-saver@2.0.1 and not file-saver@2.0.2 as in your package.json. I resolved the issue by installing the latest version of jspdf@2.1.1. I was able to remove file-saver from my package.json, and it was included in the dependencies of jspdf.

Comment: A slightly older post of yours, with identical content has been deleted by a moderator. Do you remember the reason he gave?